# limit problem: $\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\int^1_0 x^nf(x)dx $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function.I want to calculate this limit:$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\int^1_0 x^nf(x)dx  $$

Comment: Hint: $f$ is continuous on a compact interval, then it is bounded by some constant $M$. You know how to integrate $x^n$ as well...

Comment: possible dublicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128823/limit-of-integral-n-int-01-xn-fx-textdx-as-n-rightarrow-infty?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is equal to $f(1)$. Let's prove it: first, consider $(n+1) \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x)$ for simplicity (it doesnt't change the limit). Choose any $\varepsilon >0$ and find appropriate $\delta$ from definition of continuity. Then
$$
\begin{align}(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x)dx - f(1) &= (n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(f(x)-f(1))dx \\
&=(n+1)\int_{0}^{1-\delta} x^{n}(f(x)-f(1))dx + (n+1)\int_{1-\delta}^{1}x^{n}(f(x)-f(1))dx.
\end{align}$$
First term may be estimated by $2 \sup |f| (n+1) \int_{0}^{1-\delta}x^{n}dx$ and the second one by $\varepsilon \int_{1-\delta}^{1}x^{n}dx$; both expressions tend to $0$.