# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}nI_n$ with $I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

We have to evaluate: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}nI_n$$ with $$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}\:dx.$$

> There is an elegant way to solve this problem?

---

Here is all my steps:

- My first ideea was to find a recurrence relation such that:

$$I_{n+2}+3I_{n+1}+2I_n=\frac{1}{n+1},\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$$

- Next step I show that $\forall x\in[0,1]\Rightarrow I_{n}\ge I_{n+1}\ge I_{n+2}$

Therefore it involving that: $$6I_n\ge 4I_{n+1}+2I_n\ge\frac{1}{n+1},\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$$

As I said above $$6I_{n+2}\leq 4I_{n+2}+2I_n\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$$ 
$\Rightarrow \frac{n}{6(n+1)}\leq nI_n\leq\frac{n}{6(n-1)},\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$

Therefore by squeeze thereom:

$$nI_n\to\frac{1}{6}\:as\:n\to\infty$$

Comment: $$\implies I_{n+1}+3I_{n}+2I_{n-1}=\dfrac1n$$

Comment: I'd write the integrand as $\frac{x^n}{x+1}-\frac{x^n}{x+2}$

Comment: Maple suggests $\frac 1 6 .$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, recurrence is valid and perfect then. ^

Comment: @Mann, I'm trying to show $$I_m=\dfrac1{6m}+O\left(\dfrac1{m^2}\right)$$ by setting  $$I_n=\cdots+a_2n^2+a_1n+a_0+a_{-1}\dfrac1n+\cdots$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee If limit exist, we can just multiply your equality by $(n+1)$ and take limit.

Comment: Here is the general result :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128823/limit-of-integral-n-int-01-xn-fx-textdx-as-n-rightarrow-infty

Comment: @John: That was the idea I had in mind when I wrote my answer (+1) :-)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you show me your method by recurrence relation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We may just integrate by parts,
$$
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{(x+1)(x+2)}dx&=\left. \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}\right|_0^1+\frac{1}{(n+1)}\int_0^1\frac{(2x+3)\:x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^2(x+2)^2}\:dx\\\\
&=\frac1{6(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{(2x+3)}{(x+1)^2(x+2)^2}\:x^{n+1}dx\\\\
&=\frac1{6(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n+1}J_n \tag1
\end{align}
$$ and one may observe that
$$
0\leq \int_0^1\frac{(2x+3)}{(x+1)^2(x+2)^2}\:x^{n+1}dx\leq \frac{(2\times1+3)}{(0+1)^2(0+2)^2}\int_0^1x^{n+1}dx
$$ or
$$
0\leq J_n\leq \frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{(n+2)}. \tag2
$$
Then using $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives easily

> $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}nI_n=\frac16.$$

Comment: excellent answer. deserving an "upvote"....

Comment: Evaluating $\frac{2x+3}{(x^2+3x+2)^2}$ at $0$ and $1$ for the bounds assumes that it is monotone on $[0,1]$, which is not obvious to me. Using the min of the numerator and max of the denominator and vice versa, gives $$\frac3{36}\frac1{n+1}\le J_n\le\frac54\frac1{n+1}$$ which is not as tight an estimate, but tight enough.

Comment: @OlivierOloa one observation that $\int_0^1 x^{n+1}dx=\frac{1}{n+2}$

Comment: @Lucas Yes, I will edit my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OlivierOloa can you explain why you multiply at numerator with different number than denominator ? can you give some details about this method ?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, I give you some details. Assume you have $0<\frac1{B} \leq \frac1{b}$. Multiplying by any $a>0$ gives  $0<\frac{a}{B} \leq \frac{a}{b}$. Moreover if $a\leq A$, then  $0<\frac{a}{B} \leq \frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{A}{b}.$ That's what we have applied here with $x\in [0,1]$, $a=(2x+3)$, $A=5$, $B=(x+1)^2(x+2)^2$, $b=4$. Hoping this can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Substitute $x\mapsto x^{1/(n+1)}$ and use [Dominated Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem):
$$
\begin{align}
n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac1{x^2+3x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x^{n+1}\\
&=\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac1{x^{2/(n+1)}+3x^{1/(n+1)}+2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\to1\int_0^1\frac1{1+3\cdot1+2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac16
\end{align}
$$

---

**A More Basic Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac16-\left(n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac16-\frac{x^{1/n}}{x^{2/n}+3x^{1/n}+2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac16\int_0^1\left(\frac{x^{2/n}-3x^{1/n}+2}{x^{2/n}+3x^{1/n}+2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&\le\frac1{12}\int_0^1\left(x^{2/n}-3x^{1/n}+2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{12}\left(\frac{n}{n+2}-3\frac{n}{n+1}+2\right)\tag4\\[6pt]
&=\frac{7n-2}{12(n+1)(n+2)}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ then bring the $\frac16$ inside the integral
$(2)$: algebra; $x^{2/n}-3x^{1/n}+2=\left(x^{1/n}-1\right)\left(x^{1/n}-2\right)\ge0$ on $[0,1]$
$(3)$: since the integrand is positive, bound it by replacing the denominator with its minimum
$(4)$: integrate
$(5)$: simpllfy

Therefore,
$$
\frac16-\frac{7n-2}{12(n+1)(n+2)}\le\left(n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\le\frac16\tag6
$$
Apply the Squeeze Theorem to get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac16\tag7
$$

Comment: Can you justify taking the limit inside the integral?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Is it not enough that limits commute with Riemann integration?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: yes, using Dominated Convergence

Comment: @robjohn I don't think the OP will be familiar with DCT or Lebesgue integration, so it may not ultimately be helpful

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: they tagged the question [tag:real-analysis], so I used a basic tool of real analysis. If they don't know Dominated Convergence, they can look it up at the link provided and learn something new.

Comment: @robjohn I understand the purpose for you was to arrive at $\frac{1}{6}$ but why you don't directly apply dominated convergence on $\frac{1}{x^2+3x+2}$ and you change $x=x^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ ?

Comment: @Lucas: since we have $n\,x^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac n{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}x^{n+1}$, it seemed natural to substitute $x^{n+1}\mapsto x$.

Comment: @Lucas: apply Dominated Convergence on $\frac1{x^2+3x+2}$? That sequence does not change. Did you mean $\frac{n\,x^n}{x^2+3x+2}$? The limit of $n\,x^n$ on $[0,1]$ is of the indeterminate form $\infty\cdot0$. This is pretty much the reason to use the substitution $x^{n+1}\mapsto x$; the factor of $n$ becomes $\frac n{n+1}$ which disappears as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: now I understand robjohn, so isn't neccessary to write substitution with another character:  $\omega=x^{n+1}$  and by that I do not understand, or is it, and after change variable?

Comment: @Lucas: I apologize if my method of substitution is confusing. Instead of using a different variable like $u=x^{n+1}$, which is necessary in indefinite integrals in order to reverse the substitutions, in definite integrals I often use the same variable name and everywhere I see an $x$ (including the limits of integration $x=0$ and $x=1$), I write $x^{1/(n+1)}$. This saves on variables; some definite integrations require many substitutions, so I have adopted this method of substitution.

Comment: @Lucas: not at all. This change of variables can be confusing at first, and I apologize for that. However, I think it can be useful, so I don't avoid it in case it might help someone else.

Comment: and for limits of integrations, it remains same for a general case ? because we don't use a different variable, isn't it?

Comment: @Lucas: In this case, it remains the same because the limits are $0$ and $1$. For more general limits, using $x\mapsto x^2$, we get $$\begin{align}\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &=\int_{x=a}^{x=b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\int_{x^2=a}^{x^2=b}f(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x^2\\ &=2\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}f(x^2)\,x\,\mathrm{d}x\end{align}$$ Thus, we essentially apply the inverse function to the limits.

Comment: @Lucas: Where did the $2x$ in the denominator come from? Think $u^2=x$: then change the $u$ to an $x$. $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}f(u^2)\,2u\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: @Lucas: I see that people have marked this question as off-topic. It would be nice to add some context; that is, where did the question come from, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: @robjohn I'll show my solution in few minutes and I want to tell me if it is correct or not

Comment: I hope is correct

Comment: @Lucas: looks good to me!