# $I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, find $nI_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$
Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty} nI_n$$

**My approach:**
Let me explain my observations briefly.
Note that $I_{n-1}-I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}(1-x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx \ge 0$

Hence $I_n$ is decreasing.Also $I_n\ge 0$.So, $I_n$ is convergent. Let $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n =l$

Now $I_n+I_{n-2} =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n-1} -\frac{2}{n-1} I_n$
(By parts +little bit calculation)

Applying limit to the above equation we get,
$l=0$.

Also from the above equation we have,
$(n-1)I_n+(n-1)I_{n-2}=\sqrt{2}-2I_n$.
If $J_n := nI_n$, then
$\frac{n-1}{n} J_n +\frac{n-1}{n-2} J_{n-2}=\sqrt{2}-2I_n$

Yes I am only now one step away from getting $\lim_{n\to \infty} J_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

But I am unable to prove that $J_n$ is convergent

Any idea??

Comment: Also on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1772344p11637185 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24I_n%3D%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5En%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%7D%20dx%24)

Comment: Thanks. This solution is fantastic 

Answer (score 5):

[Write $\frac {nx^{n}} {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}}$ as $ ({nx^{n-1}}) ( \frac x{\sqrt {1+x^{2}}})$]. Integration by parts gives $\int_0^{1}\frac {nx^{n}} {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} dx=x^{n}\frac x {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}}|_0^{1}-\int_0^{1} x^{n}\frac d {dx} \frac x {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}}dx$. DCT shows that the second term tends to $0$. Hence the limit is $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the integration of  the term $x^n$ should give $x^{n+1}$ on the RHS. But the question is a duplicate anyway, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3600402/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I am unable to see the mistake. I have added  a line at the beginning. Please tell me if it is correct.

Comment: You are right, my fault, sorry about that. But is *is* a duplicate, easy to find with Approach0.