# Riemann-integral and Stone-Weierstrauss Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, weierstrass-approximation

**Question:**
Let ƒ be a continuous real-valued function on [0, 1].

Show that

$\lim_{n->\infty }\frac{\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{1}x^ndx} = f(1)$

**My approach:** I thought the denominator and the numerator are both differentiable in the given interval, so that I could use the L'Hospital's Theorem to prove this statement, by then making the question very straightforward.

But how can I use the Stone-Weierstrauss Theorem to prove this statement? I don't see any possible relation of solving this problem with the Stone-Weierstrauss Theorem.

Comment: Duplicate of second part of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128823/limit-of-integral-n-int-01-xn-fx-textdx-as-n-rightarrow-infty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial verification shows that the result is true when $f(x)=cx^{k}$ for some non-negative integer $k$ and $c$ is a constant. Hence it holds when  $f$ is a polynomial. Now choose a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$ (which is possible by Weierstrass Approximation Theorem). Note that $|\frac {\int x^{n}f(x)} {\int x^{n}dx}-\frac {\int x^{n}p(x)} {\int x^{n}dx}|<\epsilon$. Can you finish?

Stone-Weierstrass Theorem is much stronger than Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. For this problem you only need Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry but how did you get to the last inequality? And about the trivial verification, can this example be the general case for all f(x) that are continuous in the interval?

Comment: $|\frac {\int x^{n}f(x)} {\int x^{n}dx}-\frac {\int x^{n}p(x)} {\int x^{n}dx}|<\frac {\int x^{n}\epsilon dx} {\int x^{n}dx}=\epsilon$.